# What is Spark execution order with function calls in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, global-variables

I have a spark program as follows:

```
object A {
  var id_set: Set[String] = _

  def init(argv: Array[String]) = {
    val args = new AArgs(argv)
    id_set = args.ids.split(",").toSet
  }

  def main(argv: Array[String]) {
    init(argv)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("some.name")
    val rdd1 = getRDD(paras)
    val rdd2 = getRDD(paras)
    //......
  }

  def getRDD(paras) = {
    //function details
    getRDDDtails(paras)
  }

  def getRDDDtails(paras) = {
    //val id_given = id_set
    id_set.foreach(println)    //worked normal, not empty
    someRDD.filter{ x =>
      val someSet = x.getOrElse(...)
      //id_set.foreach(println)  ------wrong, id_set just empty set
      (some_set & id_set).size > 0
    }
  }

class AArgs(args: Array[String]) extends Serializable {
  //parse args
}
```

I have a global variable `id_set`. At first, it is just an empty set. In main function, I call `init` which sets `id_set` to a non-empty set from args. After that, I call `getRDD` function which calls `getRDDDtails`. In `getRDDDtails`, I filter a rdd based on contents in `id_set`. However, the result semms to be empty. I tried to print `is_set` in executor, and it is just an empty line. So, the problem seems to be `is_set` is not well initilized(in `init` function). However, when I try to print `is_set` in driver(in head lines of function `getRDDDtails`), it worked normal, not empty.

So, I have tried to add `val id_given = id_set` in function `getRDDDtails`, and use `id_given` later. This seems to fix the problem. But I'm totally confused why should this happen? What is the execution order of Spark programs? Why does my solution work?

Comment: You're never calling any action on your RDDs (saveAsTextFile, collect, groupBy, ..) as opposed to transformations (filter, map, flatMap, ...) which are lazy. The pipeline on your RDDs will only be executed where you call an action. In your code no actions, and thus nothing is done on your RDDs.

Comment: first of all `id_set = args.ids.split(",").toSet` assignment is wrong. You cannot assign to a immutable Set. so your id_set is never initialized and its always empty as defined in the global place.

Comment: sorry for the error. In fact, it is a var, I have changed the code.

Comment: RDD's are lazy data structures, which means that any "transform" operation ( such as `map`, `filter`, `flatMap` etc) are not actually performed but are just added to the "evaluation graph" for the next RDD. Actual evaluation of transforms takes place only when a consume operation (such as `collect`, `foreach`) is perfromed on RDD.

Comment: `id_set` is not a rdd, just a set of string. When transform happens on `someRDD`, i think `id_set` should be the latest value(not initial value). But it's wrong.